# "Normal convergence implies uniform convergence and absolute convergence". Attempt to prove it via Weierstrass M-test. What is missing?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, uniform-convergence, absolute-convergence

Let us start with a given function $f_n$ defined on a certain domain $I$ and s.t. $f_n:I\mapsto\text{ some normed vector space}$. We know that:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \|f_n\| := \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sup_I |f_n(x)| < \infty\implies \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x)\text{ is normally convergent}\tag{1}$$
I was thinking that, at this point, it could have been enough to apply the so called [Weierstrass M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test) to show that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f_n$ is uniformly and absolutely convergent as well.
However, Weierstrass M-test first requires absolute convergence of the series, that is: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty |f_n(x)|\text{ convergent}$$ and I know that in general it holds true that:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x)\text{ convergent}\nRightarrow \sum_{n=0}^\infty |f_n(x)|\text{ convergent} $$

---

Hence, starting from normal convergence of a series, how is it possible to use Weierstrass M-test so as to show that the series converges absolutely and uniformly as well? Which is the missing part above?

Comment: You wrote $\implies$ but isn't that just the definition of normal convergence?

Comment: Yeah, $(1)$ is taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_convergence in the "Definition" section @zhw.

Comment: Saying $\sum f_n$ is normally convergent is the same as saying the Weierstrass M test applies to $\sum f_n.$

Comment: So, if it is the same thing, wouldn't that mean that $$\sum f_n\text{ normally convergent}\iff\sum f_n \text{ uniformly convergent}$$ and $$\sum f_n\text{ normally convergent}\iff\sum f_n \text{ absolutely convergent}$$? But, I know that those two $\iff$ relations are not true @zhw.

Comment: No, not at all. What I'm saying is simple: The hypothesis $\sum M_n<\infty$ in the Weierstrass M test  holds iff $\sum f_n$ converges normally.

Comment: Ok, got this point. At this point, my question is: in your opinion, would it be more correct in $(1)$ to have $\iff$ instead of $\implies$? @zwh.

Comment: Why not just say "by definition ....."

Comment: Yeah...but doesn't "by definition" mean exactly $\iff$? @zwh.

Comment: I suppose so. But using $\implies$ for a definition can be confusing. In fact, I thought you were confused about it, which is why I wrote my first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $x \in I$, $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty |f_n(x)| < \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sup_{x \in I}|f_n(x)| = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \|f_n\| < \infty$$
Then by the $M$-test the series is uniformly and absolutely convergent if  the normed vector space is a Banach space.

Comment: Pardon, just one question. In your answer you are considering $(1)$ as an $\iff$ relation, if I am not wrong, aren't  you? Why that? According to $(1)$ (i.e. normal convergence definition), if I know that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f_n$ is normally convergent, I cannot be certain that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \|f_n\| := \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sup_I |f_n(x)| < \infty$ @abhi01nat

Comment: Normal convergence of the series is precisely the convergence of the sum of uniform norms, i.e., the series is defined to be normally convergent if the sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \|f_n\|$ converges. This is what the definition in the wiki page you linked to says.

Comment: Aren't "is precisely" and "if..." contradictory? I interpret "is" as an "iff" relation, i.e. $\iff$  ,and not as an "if" relation @abhi01nat

Comment: Convergent means there exists a limit point in the space. The Cauchy condition is necessary for convergence in a normed vector space but is not sufficient if is not a Banach space.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Good point.

Comment: @abhi01nat Why are you stating that $M$-test is applicable only if normed vector space is Banach? I cannot find such a fact anywhere

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Could you please give me a reference for the fact you stressed about Cauchy condition?

Comment: @Strictly_increasing . It is common standard terminology that in a normed linear space $S$,a sequence $(x_n)_n$ is called convergent only when $\|x-x_n\|\to 0$ for some $x\in S.$